# v-for depending on tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble with a very simple vue.js-app. I have a list of referees, and I want to iterate that list and append each item with data from ajax request. When I try to display that list, it works fine if I use `v-for` on `span`-element, but if I use `div` instead of `span`, it breaks. Why does it break with div?

A simplified example is here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p v-for="referee in referees">
            Name: {{referee.name}}<br>
            Match count: {{ referee.matches.length}}

            <!-- If I use span here, everything works just fine -->
            <span v-for="match in referee.matches">{{match.date}}</span>

            <!-- But if I switch to div, it no longer works -->
            <!--div v-for="match in referee.matches">{{match.date}}</div-->
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    let myReferees = [
        { name: "Referee 1", },
        { name: "Referee 2", },
        { name: "Referee 3", },
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                referees: [],
            },

            created: function () {
                for(let referee of myReferees){
                    referee.matches = [];

                    let matches = [ 
                        {date: "date1"},
                        {date: "date2"},
                        {date: "date3"},
                    ];

                    for(let match of matches){
                        referee.matches.push({
                            date: match.date,
                        });
                    }

                    this.referees.push(referee);
                }
            },
        });
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Here is a fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/vvu2f0m6/](https://jsfiddle.net/vvu2f0m6/)
The fiddle and example code are working ones, but if you change the `span` -> `div`, you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this and you should be fine . Change the `p` tag to `div`

```
<body>
        <div id="app">
            <div v-for="referee in referees">
                Name: {{referee.name}}<br>
                Match count: {{ referee.matches.length}}

                <!-- If I use span here, everything works just fine -->
                <div v-for="match in referee.matches">{{match.date}}</div>

                <!-- But if I switch to div, it no longer works -->
                <!--div v-for="match in referee.matches">{{match.date}}</div-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

You can't have `div` inside a `p`

Comment: If I set div's display to inline-block, it still doesn't work. Your solves my problem, but I'd like to understand it better.

Comment: I don't know  why is like that in Vue. I have had such cases before. It appears that Vue is very strict with document tree or object model.

Comment: Ok, seems like the problem isn't related to vue after all, but my html.

Comment: Oh great! You figured out

Comment: `<p>` tag is a block level element and it is supposed to be used to contain text (and not other elements).  `<div>` tag allows to contain block elements. so you are right @JoriO the main reason of the issue was HTML